# MTLLibrary.makefunction not found and MTLLibrary.functionNames are empty

Tags: metal

I have a metal file `Conv.metal` with two kernel functions.
I compiled the `Conv.metal` to `Conv.metallib` using `xcrun` on terminal.
Then I put it into **Copy Bundle Resources** list.

But I always got no function found when calling `makeFunction`.
The `MTLlibrary.functionNames: [String]` also return empty.

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: MY_BUNDLE_ID) // OK
let url = bundle.url(forResource: "Conv", withExtension: "metallib") // OK
let library = try! device.makeLibrary(URL: url) // OK
let kernelFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "YUVtoRGB")! // <- failure

// check library functionNames
print(library.functionNames) // <- empty []
```

But when I put my kernel functions block to another metal and rebuilt to metallib, my functions can be found and loaded OK.

My library is found and loaded, so it should not be related to bundle resource issues.

Comment: in my case the always working code suddenly broke this year and the fix was to move the metallib from subfolder "/metal" to resources root

Answer (score 0):

`Conv.metal` and `Conv.metallib` cannot have the same basename.

If I rename `Conv.metallib` to `ConvLib.metallib` or `ConvTool.metallib`, everything is fine.

Don't know the reason, but it works.

Comment: After finding half a day, renaming solves this thing.  Need note this.